# Why assembly delegatecall() returns 1 instead of 0 when calling zero (0x000...) address?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, geth, evm

I have this code in a proxy fallback:

```
assembly {
    calldatacopy(mload(0x40), 0, calldatasize())
    let result := delegatecall(gas(), destination, mload(0x40), calldatasize(), mload(0x40), 0)
    returndatacopy(mload(0x40), 0, returndatasize())
    switch result
    case 1 { return(mload(0x40), returndatasize()) }
    default { revert(mload(0x40), returndatasize()) }
}
```

The problem arises when `destination` is a zero address (0x0000000000000000000000). delegatecall goes through, returns `1`, then hits `case 1` with return data completely empty which triggers `... did it run out of gas` error (which is not really related to the question).

I have just swapped to newest Hardhat and web3 (v1.6.1) from Ganache where this would hit `default` case and revert. Is there something I do not know or was changed recently?

Comment: You can call delegatecall on external account, check this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17406/can-i-use-delegatecall-in-a-transaction

I think you can check whether address is contract.

Comment: @PeterLai yeah, security team removed the address check. it's too expensive and not that much of a problem. however, I think a check for 0 address does need to happen...